# php to strip and replace html meta tags

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I'm not very familiar with PHP overall, but I'm trying to find a way to change some parts of the following documents:

```
index.html
hidden.html
```

Both pages are using the same header include file containing `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`

but I want to use PHP for some pages to strip and replace the entire line, and replace with something like `<meta name="robots" content="none">`

Can anyone provide an example of just stripping such a thing, and also strip+replace?

Would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use str_replace to find and replace strings. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace("I want to replace this", "with this");
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll try that. But is there also a way to just strip, and not replace?

Comment: Then just do: str_replace("I want to replace this", "");